# Showing that $H$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question has been bugging me for a while. Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $Ha\not=Hb$ implies that $aH\not =bH$. I need to show that $gHg^{-1}\subset H$.(I don't mean a proper subset, just subset)

Now, take $x\in gHg^{-1}$. Suppose it is not in $H$. Then $x=ghg^{-1}$ for some $h$. As $x\not \in H$, $Hx\not=H$ whih implies $xH\not=H$ but this doesn't seem to be a terribly bright application of the given condition.(I could have got it using $x\not \in H$) Can someone give me a hint to the solution?

Comment: I think you have a typo: "Then $x = ghg^{-1}$ for some $h$. As $x \in H$…" where $\in$ should be negated?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: do you mean a proper subset or just a subset of $H$?

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $b$ are not in the same right coset then they cannot be in the same left coset. That means the only elements in the left cost $aH$ are the ones in the right coset $Ha$.